# Php - get number, not char from string

Tags: php, arrays, string, substring

I'm not very familiar with php and got stuck in how to use substr in this case:

I have to do the parse of a string that has some numbers and symbols,
example:

```
1[2[3,5],4[7[65,9,11],8]]
```

And to do this I used a for that will go through and get each char of the string,
something like that:

```
$count = 0;
for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($string); $i++){
    $char = substr($string, $i, 1);
    if($char == '['){
        $count --;
    }
    if($char == ']'){
        $count ++;
    }
    if($count == 0){
        break;
    }

    if(is_numeric(substr($string, $i +1, 1)) and $count == -1){
        $number = substr($string, $i +1, 1);
        $array_aux[] = $number;
    }

}
```

But as I'm getting the char in (substr ($ string, $ i, 1)) it does not work for numbers with more than one digit, such as 65 and 11

And the contents of the array gets something like: (..., 6, 5, 9, 1, 1, ...)

When should be something like: (..., 65, 9, 11, ...)

Any help?

Sorry, I think was not clear enough.
I need the numbers that are inside '[' when count has the value -1

(that's why I'm using substr, and taking every char)

examples: when the string is: 1[2[3,5],4[7[65,9,11],8]], the array must contain 2 and 4

when the string is: 2[3,5],4[7[65,9,11],8]], the array must contain 3 and 5

when the string is: 7[65,9,11],8]], the array must contain 65, 9 and 11. And so on...

Sorry to put these details only now, I was without computer :(

Comment: use `explode` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 6):

`preg_match_all` with a simple regular expression can do this for you:

```
$in = "1[2[3,5],4[7[65,9,11],8]]";
preg_match_all('~\d+~', $in, $out);
print_r($out[0]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 65
    [7] => 9
    [8] => 11
    [9] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and split by matching one or more times not a digit `\D+`

```
$str = "1[2[3,5],4[7[65,9,11],8]]";
print_r(preg_split("/\D+/", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 7
    [6] => 65
    [7] => 9
    [8] => 11
    [9] => 8
)
```